# 3D plot python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I would like to know how to transform data so as to obtain:
a plot of each signal from each file corresponding to an Z Value in one image.

View 3D Data with X, Y, Z .

(X,Y) from import text files and Z is a list.

X column 1 and Y column 2,

I have written some code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob,os

from matplotlib import pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d


for data in glob.iglob("S21/*.txt"):
    data = np.loadtxt(data,skiprows=21)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


    x_data = data[:, 1]
    y_data = data[:, 2]

    x_array = np.array(x_data)
    y_array = np.array(y_data)
    z_array = np.array([0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100])


    X,Y,Z = x_array, y_array, z_array

    plt.plot(X,Y,"o",label= 'Measured Data')


ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d()
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim3d()
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim3d()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Include (a link to) an image or what you're currently plotting (so we can get an idea of the data) and ideally, an image of what you want to plot. (We'll edit your post so that the links to the images show properly)

Comment: please see the images  (http://s12.postimg.org/y5m9zjk65/Fig.png
http://s12.postimg.org/5h9bwbhzx/figure_1.png
)

Comment: The data see  (http://textuploader.com/6v46!)